# I need to get value from input html FORM to using as query in database using by Mule studio

Tags: mule-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kloAE.jpg)

How can I get the value from html input from to use as query in my database in mule studio .

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" 
      port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" 
      user="root" password="Blue1234" database="news" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
<flow name="searchhtmlFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/web" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select txt from news.nws where sub=#[message.inboundProperties[q]]]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <parse-template location="C:\Users\Hersh\Desktop\attach\index.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
    <set-property propertyName="content" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.q]" doc:name="Property"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :-

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" 
      port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" 
      user="root" password="Blue1234" database="news" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
<flow name="searchhtmlFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/web" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <parse-template location="C:\Users\Hersh\Desktop\attach\index.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
        <logger message="Value from DB :- #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.q]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select txt from news.nws where sub=#[message.inboundProperties[q]]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```